# Bluecloth: markdown to HTML results in lots of empty tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, markdown, bluecloth

For example, the following markdown:

```
# Game Version
Need For Speed Most Wanted v1.3 English version.
```

Results in the following HTML:

```
<h1>Game Version</h1>
<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>Need For Speed Most Wanted v1.3 English version.</p>
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

This is even more annoying in lists where every `<li></li>` is `<br><li></li><br>`, contrary to the markdown spec. I have checked my markdown and there are no extra end-of-line spaces or anything of the sort. The data is stored as a `text` field on Heroku Postgres.

Is this a problem with Bluecloth, or am I doing something terribly wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually calling `simple_format` on the returned string in the view:

```
simple_format BlueCloth.new(@event.description)
```

Replacing `simple_format` with `raw` fixed the problem.